# Baixar uma pasta para o computador

Tags: c#, webclient

Em C# para fazer um download de um arquivo usa-se o código:

```
using System.Net;
void Baixar(string url, string saida)
{
    WebClient wc=new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), saida);
}
```

Até agora não encontrei nenhum código bem explicado, em relação a fazer o download de pastas de um servidor.

O.B.S.: Quando utilizo este mesmo código o aplicativo não relata nenhum efeito e o local onde deveria baixar os arquivos continua o mesmo.

Comment: Nao creio que exista nenhum metodo para fazer download recursivo de *paths* e todos os ficheiros contidos nesse path... O metodo `DownloadFileAsync` pode ser usado para descarregar um ficheiro individual. Vais ter de chamar esse metodo uma vez por cada ficheiro.

Comment: Uma opção é você comprimir o diretório em um Zip e mandar como um arquivo.